# Calculate the values received from the descendants in VUE

Tags: vue.js

I have a basket, there are products in the basket, each of which is a separate component, the quantity * price is calculated inside each item. The parent gets the value, now it is necessary to somehow add the values together and get the total purchase amount, how to do this? I want to explicitly go through the `queryselectorall` and get data, for example, from date attributes, I know that this will be an error.

I use vue3 composition api

[image]

```js
parent
<BasketItem
                :item="item"
                :type="i"
                @remove="Remove"
                @sum="calc"
              ></BasketItem>

child
        <div class="count-manipulate">
          <div
            class="count-manipulate-item minus"
            @click.prevent="parseInt(count) <= 1 ? count : count--"
          ></div>
          <div
            class="count-manipulate-item plus"
            @click.prevent="count++"
          ></div>
        </div>

<script setup>
let props = defineProps({
  item: {
    type: Object,
    required: true,
  },
  type: {
    type: String,
  },
});

let emit = defineEmits(["remove", "sum"]);
let sum = ref(props.item.id);
let calc = () => {
  sum.value = parseInt(count.value) * parseInt(props.item.attributes.Price);
  emit("sum", sum.value);
};
let count = ref(1);
calc();

watch(
  () => count.value,
  () => {
    calc();
  }
);
</script>
```

Comment: Why do you need to use `queryselectorall`? Are you planning to retrieve each product quantity and price using `queryselectorall`? Also, please include your code so that we can better understand and guide you in resolving your question.

Comment: @ChristopherTabula Simply put, each item in the basket has a price and quantity, the element counts the quantity multiplied by the price, and gives the result to the parent. I get a lot of results. Now the results need to be added together to get the total amount of the basket.

Comment: @ChristopherTabula We need some method that at least gets all the results, for example, such as `[100,500,300]`, and then through `reduce` I can handle it

Comment: When an item gets added/removed/modified in `BasketItem` component, you can fire an event with the data (quantity, price, etc.). Parent component can listen to this event and maintain each item's inventory. You can do the necessary calculations on this object as and when required.

Comment: @PrerakSola The component `BasketItem` counts and sends the parent `emit`, the parent element receives only the number that needs to be added to the rest of the values, the problem is how to connect them together

Comment: I would suggest you to add the code that does all of this in order to get a clear picture.

Comment: And what does `calc` method do in the parent component?

Comment: @PrerakSola Nothing, just there I would like to get a ready array of values and conduct a `reduce`

Comment: You need an array in the parent component and `calc` method can append the value it receives to that array. Then you can use `reduce` to calculate the total.

Comment: @PrerakSola That's right, I can't figure out how to collect actual
non-repeating values

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved my problem by using a reactive sessionstorage from `vueUse`

```js
let sessionOrder = useSessionStorage("basket", [] as SessionOrderType[]);

const calculateOverallTotalSum = (id: number, type: string, sum: number) => {
  if (sessionOrder.value.some((p) => p.id === id && p.type.includes(type))) {
    sessionOrder.value.map((p) => {
      if (p.id === id && p.type === type) {
        return (p.sum = sum);
      }
    });
  } else {
    let obj = {
      id: id,
      type: type,
      sum: sum,
    };
    sessionOrder.value.push(obj);
  }

  summary.value = sessionOrder.value.reduce(
    (total, item) => item.sum + total,
    0
  );
};
```

Answer (score 1):

Some advice:

- If the value of the variable is not changing, declare it as a constant.
- As much as possible, declare event handler functions if you want to update reactive states based on DOM events. As your component grows in size, it can be tiring scrolling back-and-forth from the script tag to the template tag to check which DOM event updates the state/s. Furthermore, you can better handle complex computations with it.
- If a state is dependent on another state, and that state updates on DOM events, move them inside the event handler.

**Child Component**

```html
<template>
  <!-- Sample template -->
  <div @click.prevent="calculateTotal('sub')">-</div>
  <div @click.prevent="calculateTotal('add')">+</div>
</template>

<script setup>
  import { ref } 'vue';

  const props = defineProps(/** your props */);
  const emit = defineEmits(["remove", "sum"]);

  const count = ref(0);
  const sum = ref(0);

  /** Handler for the @click event */
  const calculateTotal = (operation) => {
    if (operation === 'add') {
      count.value += 1;
    } else if (operation === 'sub' && count.value > 0) {
      count.value -= 1;
    }

    // You don't need to parseInt unless the value is not a number.
    sum.value = count.value * props.item.attributes.Price;

    emit('sum', { id: props.item.id, sum: sum.value });
  };
</script>
```

Now, in your parent component, render your child components using `v-for`. Then, declare a state that contains the `overallTotalSum` of your basket. Finally, like the child component, create a handler that will grab the emitted basket item sum then do the necessary computation.

**Parent Component**

```html
<template>
  <BasketItem
    v-for="item in items"
    :key="item.id"
    :item="item"
    @sum="calculateOverallTotalSum"
  />
</template>

<script setup>
  import { ref } 'vue';
  import BasketItem from 'path';

  const items = ref([/** your basket items */]);
  const overallTotalSum = ref(0);

  const calculateOverallTotalSum ({ id, sum }) => {
    items.value = items.value.map(item => {
      if (item.id === id) {
        item.sum = sum;
      }

      return item
    });

    overallTotalSum.value = items.value.reduce(
      (total, item) => item.sum + total, 0
    );
  };
</script>
```